# Write on the page "about us" Broadleaf Commerce

Tags: broadleaf-commerce

I'm doing a project for the university on e-commerce and I decided to use broadleafcommerce, the thing is that I want to put a Google maps (scripts) in the shop template, I have managed to put them on the main page but what I want to do is put them in the page "about us" but in the project directory (I use intelliJ idea) I can not find the html associated to "about us".

My question is, how can I write code on the page "about us" to put the maps there?

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

"about us" is a page created by the admin and you can call the template you want. If it is the "default"  one you can find it on webTemplates-> default.html. Obviously this will affect every page you create via admin with this template.

Other solution would be to write your own simple "get" controller and return a new template.

Comment: Thank you, I write the controller and I could do what I wanted.